# Avoid browser window on run ionic:serve

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to start an ionic server with `--no-open` enabled on run `ionic serve`, as described in [ionic CLI documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/serve/).

But, in the generated file I need to use `npm run ionic:serve`. I'm trying to add an extra parameter on file `package.json` like:

```
"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve --no-open"
```

It doesn't works.

Maybe, there is some property in file `ionic.config.json` that allows me to do it.

So, I have two questions:

1. How can I avoid to open a browser window using `npm run ionic:serve`?
2. Where can I find a complete list of all available properties and their valid values applied to file `ionic.config.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct parameter is `--nobrowser` instead of `--no-open` as described in the documentation.

I've noticed the parameter in the [github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/blob/8f71e358ec5fec500d5481d5a166d1bddc711cde/src/serve.ts) repository of [`ionic-app-scripts`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts).